# Calculating date differences in Excel data

Tags: python, excel

I have a scenario where I have to read an Excel file and calculate the date difference for each status and store the output in another Excel file.

```
date    name    status
1/15/2017   ABC insert_start
1/16/2017   ABC insert_complete
1/17/2017   DEF remove_start
1/18/2017   DEF remove_complete
1/19/2017   GHI create_start
1/20/2017   GHI create_complete
```

I need the output in the following format:

```
name    created inserted    removed
ABC        0        1          0
DEF        0        0          1
GHI        1        0          0
```

Where value `1` is the date difference of `ABC` to complete insert status.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please show us the code you have tried to use and describe how it does or does not meet the requirements. Keep in mind that SO is not a free code writing service.

Comment: I tried using openpyxl package to read the excel file. not sure how to iterate each names and transpose it to the new format.

Comment: Excel already codes dates as a number of days, just do a subtraction.

Comment: I need to achieve this in python.since the number of rows are high. Also the status which I posted is only 3. but actually there are 20+ statuses.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say `df` is the dataframe created by loading the excel file (which looks like the one in your example). You might have loaded it with

```
df = pd.read_csv('foo.csv', sep='\s+', parse_dates=['date'])
```

Now, you can do this:

```
pivoted = df.pivot('name', 'status').fillna(0)
ops = ("create", "insert", "remove")
result = pd.concat([  pivoted['date', op + '_complete'] 
                    - pivoted['date', op + '_start'] 
                    for op in ops], axis=1)
result.columns = ops
#       create  insert  remove
#name                        
#ABC   0 days  1 days  0 days
#DEF   0 days  0 days  1 days
#GHI   1 days  0 days  0 days
```

Comment: Thanks. forgot to mention i will have duplicate statuses in the file which i don't want to consider. I am getting an error "ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape".Pls help